# HTML Layer of Color

Tags: html

So I just started learning HTML and I was wondering how I can use CSS to apply a layer of color above the bgcolor, but underneath text or something. For example, the black color at the bottom of this website. I've searched stackoverflow for this question but either I didn't phrase it right when searching or it's not there. Can someone either link me to a page or explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Most elements can have a [`background-color` set with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```